# paramaterising $http response handling function in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, https

I am trying to pass a query string to a function as a paramater along with "$http" to get some data returned using Angular (see code below).

I'm sure it's something basic but I've spent 2 days on it looking through Stack Overflow, ProAngularJS book, w3c online Javascript and Angular documentation, Code Academy angularJS...  and am well and truly stuck.

If I remove the 'SELECT' from the function call and the querystring paramater from the function definition it works fine but I need to pass the query string as a paramater to the function ...

code below...

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>HHLDSummaryProj </title>
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js">        </script>
   <script         src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular-    route.min.js"></script>
   <script>
      var summaryApp = angular.module("summaryApp", ['ngRoute']);

      summaryApp.config(['$routeProvider',
         function($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider.
               when('/viewCounts', {
                  templateUrl: 'count.htm',
                  controller: 'topSummaryCtrl'
               }).
               otherwise({
                  redirectTo: '/viewCounts'
              });
         }]);

    /* inject $scope object and data retrieval factories */
    summaryApp.controller('topSummaryCtrl', function($scope, itemSummary){

        itemSummary.success(function(response, "SELECT") { 
            $scope.itemSummaryResults = response.results.bindings;
        });
    });

    summaryApp.factory('itemSummary', function($http, querystring){
        /* 1 count of data triples */
        var query = encodeURIComponent(querystring+' (COUNT(*) AS ?no) { ?s ?p ?o      }');
        var endpoint = "http://localhost:3030/dataset/query";
        return $http.get("http://localhost:3030/dataset/query?query="+query+"&output=json&stylesheet=")
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
   <h2>Your Data Looks Like This ... </h2>
   <div ng-app="summaryApp">
      <div ng-view></div>
      <script type="text/ng-template" id="count.htm">
        <table>
            <tr ng-repeat="x in itemSummaryResults">
                <td>Count of data "records" or "triples": {{ x.no.value }}    </a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
      </script> <!-- end viewCounts -->
   </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try to put only the code that is needed and a simple example with less code that we can try in a plunk or something like that please

Comment: that is only the code that's needed! I'll try and make a simpler example of the same fail and post it to supplement. Two ticks.

Comment: Hi Nada, hopefully this shorter example OK, just put it all in a HTML file for ease of replication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really basic example how to pass data to a factory:

```
var summaryApp = angular.module("summaryApp", [])

.controller('topSummaryCtrl', ['$scope', 'itemSummary', function($scope, itemSummary) {

    itemSummary.getItems("12345").success(function(response) { //"12345" is the value passed to the factory
      console.log(response);
    }).error(function(response){
      console.log(response);
    });

}]).factory('itemSummary', ['$http', function($http) {

    return {
        getItems: function(querystring) { //querystring equals to "12345"
          return $http.get("http://echo.jsontest.com/uid/" + querystring + "/value/nuno_bettencourt");
        },
        pushItems: function(object) {
          //do what you want etc etc "itemSummary.pushItems()"
        }
    };

}]);
```

Is that what you required?

In your example you was passing the "querystring" variable as a dependency like a service, factory, provider...

Another thing... are you sure you want to pass a complete sql QUERY as a URL param? DROP TABLE, TRUNCATE TABLE...

Comment: Nada, you are a legend. Thank you. Posted code with query rather than "12345" just in case anyone else wants for reference though I'm sure they could figure it out by applying your reply like I did!

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness of reference, here is my original code amended to use Nada's method above:

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>HHLDSummaryApp </title>
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js">    </script>
   <script     src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular-    route.min.js"></script>
   <script>
      var summaryApp = angular.module("summaryApp", ['ngRoute']);

  summaryApp.config(['$routeProvider',
     function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
           when('/viewCounts', {
              templateUrl: 'count.htm',
              controller: 'topSummaryCtrl'
           }).
           otherwise({
              redirectTo: '/viewCounts'
          });
     }]);


summaryApp.controller('topSummaryCtrl', ['$scope', 'itemSummary', function($scope, itemSummary) {

itemSummary.getItems("SELECT (COUNT(*) AS ?no) { ?s ?p ?o }").success(function(response) { //"12345" is the value passed to the factory
    $scope.itemSummaryResults=response.results.bindings;
  console.log(response);
}).error(function(response){
  console.log(response);
});

}]).factory('itemSummary', ['$http', function($http) {

return {
    getItems: function(querystring) { //querystring equals to "12345"
      return $http.get("http://localhost:3030/dataset/query?query=" + querystring + "&output=json&stylesheet=");
    },
    pushItems: function(object) {
      //do what you want etc etc "itemSummary.pushItems()"
    }
};

}]);

</script>
</head>

<body>
   <h2>Your Data Looks Like This ... </h2>
   <div ng-app="summaryApp">
      <div ng-view></div>
      <script type="text/ng-template" id="count.htm">
        <table>
            <tr ng-repeat="x in itemSummaryResults">
                <td>Count of data "records" or "triples": {{ x.no.value }}        </a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
      </script> <!-- end viewCounts -->
   </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Query paramaterised, grateful thanks!